# crontab settings

Tags: cron, scheduled-task

I'm having trouble running a cron job at particular times during the day.

Will this crontab setting run the command at
3am, 6am, noon, 6pm, and 9pm?

```
0 3,6,12,18,21 * * * command
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If that is in a user crontab (edited with `crontab -e` or `crontab -e -u username`), then yes.

If that is in the system crontab (`/etc/crontab`), it needs a username, i.e.

```
0 3,6,12,18,21 * * * run-as-this-username command
```

Comment: the job already runs each hr.

Answer (score 2):

Your cron specification is correct.  If it doesn't appear to be running, it may be a PATH problem (i.e., your script references something in /usr/local/bin).  If that's the case, you can stick something like

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

etc., at the top of your crontab to set the PATH for the cron jobs.  (You can do something like "echo $PATH" at the command line to see the current PATH).

Comment: path is not a problem

Answer (score 1):

Yes, afaik,  this should work. Did you already try it?

Comment: no but it already runs using this: 0 * * * * command